Pathway enrichment analysis - minimum amount of proteins?
I have 6 proteins significantly associated with an outcome and have done a pathway enrichment analysis (PEA) with them (in both Enrichr and R with the same outcome). However, I wonder if that is too small a number of proteins to use in PEA? Is the risk for false negatives too high for example? I've heard that a minimum of 10-20 genes/proteins is preferable. But is it wrong or just not super good to go below that? Thanks!
